# GroupBy, column selection and mean in python-polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I'm trying to translate this pandas statement:

```
  df.groupby(['X', 'Y'])['Z'].mean()
```

to polars, but i'm stuck at this point:

```
  df.group_by(['X', 'Y'], maintain_order=True).select(pl.col('Z').mean()
```

where i get this error:

```
  AttributeError: 'GroupBy' object has no attribute 'select'
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: [`GroupBy.agg()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/dataframe/api/polars.dataframe.group_by.GroupBy.agg.html#polars.dataframe.group_by.GroupBy.agg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close

```py
df.group_by(['X', 'Y'], maintain_order=True).agg(pl.col('Z').mean()
```

Comment: There you go, that's what i needed. Thank you!